# Problem setting up an ssh tunnelling/forwarding through bastion host

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh, bastion-host

I have the following problem I'm trying to solve.

I wanted to use deployHQ to deploy code on commits to my repository.

deployHQ configuration asks for `Hostname` `Port` `Username` and no-password.
deployHW are using Keypairs for identity validation (and authorization), so deployHQ provide me with a public-key to setup in my end machine authorized_keys store.

But, my machine is on a Private VPC in AWS.

So, I thought I can setup an **SSH proxy**, that operates on different ports.
Each port would proxy the connection to a different machine on the Private VPC part.

But, I am literally clueless on how to do it!! I understand it's not SSH tunnelling, and not TCP forwarding, but nothing really works for me.

The general idea is simple:
SSH using port 18022 to my bastion/proxy **to** funnel the communication to 10.10.0.2:22 in AWS Private VPC

SSH using port 18023 to my bastion/proxy **to** machine B:22

SSH using port 18024 to my bastion/proxy **to** machine C:22

SSH using port 18025 to my bastion/proxy **to** machine D:22

If anyone knows how to do this, or, thinks of better idea, I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: I actually solved this with reverse NAT, so, everything's cool.

Answer (score 0):

So... the solution to this is actually very simple...
Setting up reverse NAT on IpTables on the Bastion, pointing external ports to resolve to 22 on different servers.

Super simple.